# Align text in center after changing text size and typeface

Tags: android, button, view, text-size, android-typeface

I have a button and the text is perfectly in the center, but after changing the typeface and size the text is no longer centered but more in the right bottom:

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/xbtn_bg"
                    android:text="TestButton"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

In the activity:

```
Button1.setTypeface(CustomTypeFace);
Button1.setTextSize(40);
```

How can I have either the button re-adjust or move the text to the center?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
button.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
```

see
[Setting button alignment programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042643/setting-button-alignment-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: keeps doing the same, maybe it's something in the typeface I'm using